# regex with quotation mark

Tags: expression, quotes

How do I use .js to regex out the quotation marks in the following string?

```
var wtfx = "<div>ExternalClass=5"</div>44FB";


var wtf = /<div>ExternalClass.*>/;


 wtf = wtfx.replace(wtf, "");

 alert(wtf);
```

shows this does not work.  If I take the '"' out then it does.  How do I 'escape' the quote?

for example I'd like to use reg ex on the above wtf string to yield only the string 44FB.

not getting this.

Answer (score 0):

The following Code will alert "44FB":

```
var wtfx = "<div>ExternalClass=5\"</div>44FB";
var wtf = /<div>ExternalClass.*>/;
wtf = wtfx.replace(wtf, "");
alert(wtf);
```

The only change is the Backslash before the Quotationmark in line 1.

However, I'm not 100% sure if that is what you want. Feel free to write a comment if you need another result.